# The cart needs to be database based and not session based in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have Implemented Cart using Session but my project requirements is shown bellow

The cart needs to be database based and not session based.
Make use of Cart library in this application
Store the cart information into database ( not to be stored in sessions) along with the user ID
When user is logged in again, need to display the cart products in his account

I have stroked the above functionality .Actually i have used developed based on bellow example 
[example found here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/)

please help me how can implementing this please

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of CI Shopping Cart Class,

"Important: The Cart class utilizes CodeIgniter's Session Class to save the cart information to a database, so before using the Cart class you must set up a database table as indicated in the Session Documentation , and set the session preferences in your application/config/config.php file to utilize a database.".

That means before using the Cart class, you must setup the configuration to store the session in the database. That means, your cart is stored in the db.

Comment: Hi Ramesh   $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
            $config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';   i have configured and data also stored in to the table ci_sessions but i want how to store the perticular user cart data

Comment: Looks Good. This will store the cart in database.

Comment: Ramesh Here i want store the user id and his/her cart data .how can implement this please help me ramesh

Comment: Ok.. Please take a look at http://www.heroframework.com/user_guide/developers/reference/cart_model.html

Comment: ramesh i want only used codeigniter cart library how can implement this